# Extracting RGB components of images in an Array of images (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, rgb, correlation

I have five images in an array. And I want to check the histogram (correlation coefficient) of a test image with one of the image in the array. For this the approach what I used is, to calculate the correlation coefficient of one of the components of the test image with that of an image in the array. When I try to do that using the following code, I got the error at the end.

```
%storing 5 jpg images of the same size in 3D array
TargetImageArray=cat(3,'1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg');
TestImage=imread('1.jpg');
%Extracting the first image in the image array TargetImageArray 
TargetImage=TargetImageArray(:,:,1);
%correlation coefficient of the red component of the TestImage and TargetImage
Corr_Coefficient = corr2(TargetImage(:,:,1),TestImage(:,:,1));
```

But the error I got is:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in TestComponent (line 6)
Corr_Coefficient = corr2(TargetImage(:,:,1),TestImage(:,:,1));
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to acces a matrix element that does not exist. If this error occurs and you don't see the reason at once, put a breakpoint in the repsective line and check what matrix elements are accesed in that line.

In your example you're trying to acces the third dimension of matrix `TargetImage` which is just a one-dimensional array of characters (it's the image file name). This is a consequence of line 5, where you forgot to read the image. Change it to

```
TargetImage=imread(TargetImageArray(:,:,1));
```